# Unexpected end of input error in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove unexpected end of input error ?I am trying to split a string and try to store objects in an array .while doing this I am getting  Unexpected end of input

here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/v4upwhx4/

```
var arr =str.split("$#^");
var finalArray=[];

for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(JSON.parse(arr[i]))
   finalArray[i] =JSON.parse(arr[i]);
}



 console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: your last array item cannot be JSON parsed

Comment: Hint: what is `arr.length`? And what would you expect it to be?

Comment: oh sorry by mistask thanks for answer...downvoter please comment

Comment: I got it ...thanks for idea ..downvoter please comment first .As I tried this Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you have done `var arr =str.split("$#^");` the `arr` will contain 5 elements in the array wherein the **last element is empty**.

When you call `JSON.parse(arr[i]` on the last element it is going to parse an empty string which is not possible and hence the error.

Try using the `for` loop as

```
for (var i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){...}
```

Now you will not get any error.